# Nonrecursive Multilevel makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am starting to work on a project that I would like to grow to be fairly large. I Want to create a makefile that will grow with the project without much maintenance. Here is the directory structure that I have right now.

```
.
+--src
|  +--part1
|  |  +--part1.c
|  |  +--part1.h
|  +--part2
|  |  +--part2.c
|  |  +--part2.h
.  .
.  .
.  .
|  +--partN
|  |  +--partN.c
|  |  +--partN.h
+--test
|  +--part1_tests
|  |  +--part1_testX.c
|  |  +--part1_testY.c
.  .
.  .
.  .
+--obj
|  +--part1.o
|  +--part2.o
.  .
.  .
.  .
|  +--partN.o
+--a.out
```

I have never had a project of this scale and never needed to make a make file for such a project.  How would I design a makefile for this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use automatic dependency handling? And if so, where do you want the dependency files (e.g. `part5.d`) to go?

Comment: I have never used those. I don't know how they work.  Are they necessary?

Comment: No, they're an advanced trick that lets Make do some clever things automatically. Without them, you might have to take care of them by hand or do without them.

Comment: Could you point me to a resource on how to use them?

Comment: Use https://github.com/igagis/prorab/blob/master/wiki/TutorialBasicConcepts.md

Comment: Sure, but one step at a time. What do you want to do with the files in `test/`? I presume they are to be linked against the corresponding objects from `src/`. Are they code for free-standing executables? Where do you want their binaries to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to do it, but i would start by not letting the makefile grow with the project. Instead I would use the regular structure to define rules to handle projects with one codefile in one directory, to big projects with thousend of files.

For example lets play a little bit with your structure (not tested might have some typos and I assume that you start make from project dir):

```
 # we nead the header directory 
 INCDIRS        = src

 # collect every cpp file
 CXXSRCS  = $(shell find src/ -type f -name '*.cpp' 2>/dev/null)

 # now generate the object file names
 OBJSTMP  = $(CXXSRCS:%.cpp=obj/%.o)

 # compiled the source file
 obj/%.o: src/%.cpp 
      $(CXX) ${CXXFLAGS} $(foreach bin,${INCDIRS},-I${bin}) -o "$@" "$<"
```

now lets say your `main` is in `part1.cpp`:

```
ifneq (,$(wildcard src/part1/part1.cpp))

# I just dont like a.out...
executable=${APPLICATION_NAME}

# now lets build the exe:
${executable}: ${OBJS}
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
endif
```

now the last thing is a little cosmetic:

```
.PHONY: clean all

all: install

compile: ${OBJS}

package: compile ${executable}
    #now we can move the object files to were they should be
    mv -f obj/part*/* obj/

install: package
```

no matter how big your project is gonna be this makefile will do some of your steps. Its just to give your an idea. I ignored the test_files. But thinking ahead you can collect the test sources in the same way like I did with the normal sources.

So my point is, there is absolutely no reason why your makefile has to grow with the **size** of your project, only with its **complexity**.

For more information, look in the Documentation here at stackoverflow, there is plenty information for makefiles...

Hope that helps,

Kai